# how to get the date of a commit using octokit.rb

Tags: ruby, github, octokit

So I can grab the commits from a repo using:

`commits = Octokit.commits('tansaku/gitimmersion')`

but I can't work out how to get the date of a commit. If I pp an individual commit I can see dates are present:

`#<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045935358
 @_agent=<Sawyer::Agent https://api.github.com/>,
 @_fields=#<Set: {:author, :committer, :message, :tree, :comment_count}>,
 @_metaclass=#<Class:#<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045935358>>,
 @_rels=#<Sawyer::Relation::Map: [:self]>,
 @attrs=
  {:author=>
    #<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045932590
     @_agent=<Sawyer::Agent https://api.github.com/>,
     @_fields=#<Set: {:name, :email, :date}>,
     @_metaclass=#<Class:#<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045932590>>,
     @_rels=#<Sawyer::Relation::Map: []>,
     @attrs=
      {:name=>"Sam Joseph",
       :email=>"tansaku@gmail.com",
       :date=>2014-03-10 14:35:53 UTC}>,
   :committer=>
    #<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb0459302b8
     @_agent=<Sawyer::Agent https://api.github.com/>,
     @_fields=#<Set: {:name, :email, :date}>,
     @_metaclass=#<Class:#<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb0459302b8>>,
     @_rels=#<Sawyer::Relation::Map: []>,
     @attrs=
      {:name=>"Sam Joseph",
       :email=>"tansaku@gmail.com",
       :date=>2014-03-10 14:35:53 UTC}>,
   :message=>"using command lines",
   :tree=>
    #<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045927aa0
     @_agent=<Sawyer::Agent https://api.github.com/>,
     @_fields=#<Set: {:sha}>,
     @_metaclass=#<Class:#<Sawyer::Resource:0x007fb045927aa0>>,
     @_rels=#<Sawyer::Relation::Map: [:self]>,
     @attrs={:sha=>"11b345c2fc315b5f7ae6db2e0f6b0570780c20d1"}>,
   :comment_count=>0}>`

but I can't seem to extract them from these Sawyer objects.

`1.9.3-p392 :043 > pp commits[0].author.date
nil
 => nil`

`1.9.3-p392 :047 > pp commits[0].committer.date
nil
 => nil`

Now clearly I'm just being really stupid, but can someone explain how I can get these dates out of the Sawyer objects?

Many thanks in advance
CHEERS> SAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be the solution to your dilemma?

`commits[0].commit.author[:date]`
 
  `=> 2014-03-10 14:35:53 UTC`
  
  `commits[0].commit.committer[:date]`
  
 `=> 2014-03-10 14:35:53 UTC`

Comment: excellent @thomas - many thanks! Interesting though how that doesn't seem intuitive based on the dump of the object - I couldn't find reference to this in the documentation - did I miss some important part of it perhaps ...

Comment: True. I figured it out by old fashioned try and error. That is not how it should be done. ;-)